# Get a notification when client connects to access point?

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I have a question:

Is there any why to get a notification (intent, broadcast etc..) in my MainActivity when a client connects to the Wifi Access Point I openend before?

I want to print information about connected clients to a console when they connect.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
        if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
            String mac = splitted[3];
            if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                macCount++;
            } 
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```